# How to use neural networks to learn a probability density function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

For example, if we want to learn the pdf or a normal distribution, we can let the network out the mean and variance parameters of the pdf function. However, for other general/unknown distribution, is it possible for the neural network to learn the conditional pdf of observed data?
I found some reference such as [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-21501-8_8). However, I m not quite sure how their first step of creating a universe set from the observed data (page 59). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with auto encoders? Does that work here? Why are you estimating distributions in the first place?

Comment: The link you provided looks to be restricted to individuals who have an account with Macquarie University. I suggest providing the actual citation (authors, title, year) and a more accessible link.

Comment: The referenced paper from the link is “Estimate of a Probability Density Function through Neural Networks” by Leonardo Reyneri, Valentina Colla, and Marco Vannucci. It seems like auto encoders VAE or NIM-VL/VM could help you more